# problem running webapp

Tags: java, eclipse, memcached, jetty

I'm  running a webapp from eclipse helios using the jetty plugin. In debug mode the apps seems to run very slow (almost stall) and I can't get the app even to startup. When running in normal mode or in debug from command line (using mvn jetty:run) the app works ok. Any ideas?

I'm using the latest run-jetty-run plugin in a core I5 on a windows enviroment.  The webapp also makes use of a memcache server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me before - i.e. only affecting Eclipse debug mode (but Tomcat, not Jetty).

In my case, I had to wipe all my breakpoints. Once I did that, it would start up fine and I could begin adding break points again.

It only seemed to happen after a long term accrual of a lot of break points.